# Could we see edits in rendered output without highlighting, please?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, code-formatting, markdown, diff

In the review queue we can view the changes as "rendered output" or "markdown".

Sometimes I come across reviews that look like this:

[image: Review in rendered output]

I find this hard to read with all the green highlighting going on. I'd prefer to see what it will *actually* look like.

In this particular case I wonder whether all the code formatting of `Tkinter` really helps readability and I'd like to have seen it the same way as it will appear once it has been successfully reviewed.

I suggest having a third view "rendered without highlighting".

Comment: I prefer to see the differences between the posts highlighted.

Comment: @TinyGiant: this is a feature request, not a change request: I want a third button, not change the existing one. In many cases the highlighting is useful. I clarified that in the question

Comment: I still disagree, as this would lead to people just viewing that view and robo-approving even more crap edits than they already do.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Ok, I can live with such an opinion. You could even give it as an answer and we'll see how people vote on it.

Comment: I could, but I won't. I find one sentence answers rather pointless.

Comment: *"In this particular case I wonder whether all the code formatting of Tkinter really helps readability"* No, that's pretty obvious. Applying inline code formatting to random words has quite the opposite effect of making the code more readable. This is something that [people commonly do to try and game reputation from the suggested edits system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back). If they've made no significant changes other than adding backticks, you should always reject these.

Comment: @CodyGray: I was looking for a "too minor" reason, but it seems it's not available any more.